# Expected value of $\mathrm{tr}((X + D)^{-1})$ where $X$ is Wishart and $D$ is diagonal?

Tags: reference-request, random-matrices

Let $X$ be a standard Wishart matrix, i.e.,
$$
X = \sum_{j=1}^n g_j \otimes g_j \quad \mbox{where} \quad g_j \sim N(0, I_d). 
$$
Above, $g_j$ are independent samples from the standard multivariate Gaussian.

Is it possible to calculate the expected value of
$$
\mathrm{tr}((X + D)^{-1}), 
$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries?